# Using external inputs to be included based on \if switches

Tags: input

I am working on a specifications file which should be used for multiple projects. Ideally what I would like to have is a generic latex file where I can enable project specific additions, but these additions would be different for each project. At the moment I am using `\if` statements, but this leads to very unreadable tex code. Ideally I would like to externalised these things into separate files. How would I achieve this?

Example:

```
%TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\title{Specs for Project}
\newif\ifprojectA
\projectAfalse
\newif\ifprojectB
\projectBfalse
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}
The font in this project used should be \ifprojectA Times New Roman
\else \ifprojectB Palatino \else
Helvetica \fi
\end{document}
```

So if none of the projects are defined, I get a default, but if I set one of the projects to true I get a specific project result. Instead of all of these `\if` and putting the specific text inside the `\if` I would like to be able to refer to an external page where I can insert the relevant text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have almost found a solution, based on the linked related section on this page: [\input only part of a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file?rq=1). What I am doing now is to use the `catchfilebetweentags` package which allows me to include LaTex based on tags. This together with a short `\newcommand` lets me choose the text snippets I want to include. To optimise this, I only would like to get rid of having to need a default file, so that the text remains more readable.

So the solution looks for like this:

```
%TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\title{Specs for Project}
\newif\ifprojectA
\projectAfalse
\newif\ifprojectB
\projectBfalse
\newcommand{\loadText}[1]{% define command
    \ifprojectA\ExecuteMetaData[ProjectA.tex]{#1}%
    \else\ifprojectB\ExecuteMetaData[ProjectB.tex]{#1}%
    \else\ExecuteMetaData[Default.tex]{#1}%
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}
The default font for this project should be \loadText{font}.
```

\end{document}

I now have  3 tex files called `ProjectA.tex`, `ProjectB.tex` and `Default.tex` which will be used depending which project is active.

So `Default.tex` would look like:

```
%<*font>%
Helvetica%
%</font>
```

ProjectA.tex would be:

```
%<*font>
Palatino
%</font>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use files with name `projectAfile1.tex` and `projectBfile1.tex` and then use

```
\projectinput{file1}
```

with the definition

```
\newcommand*\projectinput[1]{\input{project\ifprojectA A\else B\fi#1}}
```

Or, may be **easier**, have two folders `projectA` and `projectB` with files `file1.tex` inside both folders and then in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\edef\input@path{{project\ifprojectA A\else B\fi/}}
\makeatother
```

and then use in the document

```
\input{file1} % or \include{file1}
```

which would be chosen depending on `\ifprojectA`. (I simplified the `\if … fi` but I think it's easy enough to get the idea.)