# Creating a more modular system

Tags: sectioning, packages

Though my question may be a basic one, I hope one can help me by being clear about what to do. I am using an apj emulate document on ShareLatex for my writing. My writing is long and has many sections and images. Therrefore, I want to write the different sections in component files and also have one file named 'images' exclusively for my pictures to be included in different places in the component files. I wonder how I might do this in the simplest way. What packages do I need to use and how do I go about doing it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want a single file containing all your images and call them separately?

Comment: I think you need to see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file

Comment: Is a file named 'images' actually a folder? A folder containing .png or similar graphic files to be used as parameters to `\includegraphics` commands? Or is it a literal .tex file with figure environments?

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: As it stands, the question is unclear. Please edit the question to clarify what you want.