# Input a parameter from another file

Tags: input

Thank to the people asking and answering [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file) for how to import a part of a file into Latex. I want to extend this question a bit more.

What if you have such a file resulted from a C++ simulation:

parmeters.tex

```
time=5 sec
max_velocity=3 m/s
tolerance=$10^{-6}$
start_time=349872034 sec
stop_time=349872039 sec
distance=11 m
```

In my latex, I would like to type

```
The trajectory travels the distance of \paraminput[distance]{parameters.tex} in 
\paraminput[time]{parameters.tex}. The simulation stops when the relative error is
less than \paraminput[tolerance]{parameters.tex}. The maximum observed velocity 
is \paraminput[max_velocity]{parameters.tex}. ...
```

And the result

```
The trajectory travels the distance of 11 m in 
5 sec. The simulation stops when the relative error is
less than $10^{-6}$. The maximum observed velocity 
is 3 m/s. ...
```

So I do not need to change the report everytime I run the simulation.

How is it possible in Latex?

Comment: Is the order of the parameters in the output always the same?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, the program gives the parameters always in the same order but I dont want to account on it. I want it finds the value from the name not the line as it is error prone.

Comment: Did you consider using `R` and `Sweave`? And: Would it be possible to get the C++ program output with quotation marks, i.e. `time="5 sec"`?

Comment: Easy to preprocess that with `sed` and shorten the hassle of having to write `\paraminput[<value>]{<input file>}`, which seems pointlessly verbose unless you are planning on using several different input files in the same main  `.tex` file.

Comment: vaettchen, it is possible to save with quotes. there is not limitation about that. How does it help?

Comment: I suggest to provide usage of `\SI{...}` with `siunitx` package generated by the `C++` code to get better display of numbers and units in the `.pdf` output

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I had not heard about it. I will check it and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `expl3` based solution, reading the file, storing the contents and matching the first `[#1]` parameter.

It would be better to read the file once instead of opening and closing it all the time (I will provide another solution later on)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \ar_param_file

\seq_new:N \g_ar_param_seq


\cs_new:Nn \ar_read_by_line:n {%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {#1}% Appending the current line to the global sequence buffer
}




\NewDocumentCommand{\paraminput}{O{}m}{%
  \seq_gclear:N \g_ar_param_seq% Clearing the sequence
  \ior_open:Nn \ar_param_file {#2} % Open the input file
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \ar_param_file {\ar_read_by_line:n{##1}}% Reading line by line
  \ior_close:N \ar_param_file% Closing the line
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {% Traversing through the line
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {=} {##1} % Splitting each line into 'key=value' pairs
    \seq_if_in:NxT \l_tmpa_seq {#1} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}\seq_map_break:}% Checking if `#1` is in the sequence and display it with \seq_item:Nn..., then break the mapping loop.
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The trajectory travels the distance of \paraminput[distance]{parameters.tex} in 
\paraminput[time]{parameters.tex}. The simulation stops when the relative error is
less than \paraminput[tolerance]{parameters.tex}. The maximum observed velocity 
is \paraminput[max_velocity]{parameters.tex}. ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \ar_param_file

\seq_new:N \g_ar_param_seq


\cs_new:Nn \ar_read_by_line:n {%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {#1}
}

\tl_new:N \g_paramfile_path_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\parampath}{m}{%
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_paramfile_path_tl {#1}
}





\NewDocumentCommand{\paraminput}{O{}m}{%
  \seq_gclear:N \g_ar_param_seq
  \ior_open:Nn \ar_param_file {\g_paramfile_path_tl #2}
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \ar_param_file {\ar_read_by_line:n{##1}}
  \ior_close:N \ar_param_file
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {=} {##1}
    \seq_if_in:NxT \l_tmpa_seq {#1} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}\seq_map_break:}
  }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The trajectory travels the distance of \paraminput[distance]{parameters.tex} in 
\paraminput[time]{parameters.tex}. The simulation stops when the relative error is
less than \paraminput[tolerance]{parameters.tex}. The maximum observed velocity 
is \paraminput[max_velocity]{parameters.tex}. ...


\parampath{/tmp/output_from_simulation/}
The trajectory travels the distance of \paraminput[distance]{parameters.tex} in 
\paraminput[time]{parameters.tex}. The simulation stops when the relative error is
less than \paraminput[tolerance]{parameters.tex}. The maximum observed velocity 
is \paraminput[max_velocity]{parameters.tex}. ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. may I please ask you if it is possible to add another command to set a prefix path for it such as `\parampath{/path/to/folder}`.  so `\paraminput[distance]{parameters.tex}` will be interpreted into `\paraminput[distance]{/path/to/folder/parameters.tex}`?

Comment: @ar2015: See the update please -- it's possible. Initially, the content of the `\l_paramfile_path_tl` variable is empty, i.e. the local directory is searched

Comment: Thanks. That works perfect. The author of the latex file just have to be careful of putting a `/` at the end of path.

Comment: @ar2015: Well, a test if the file exists at all could be done, of course

Comment: +1 it is the portable solution `texlive-latex-extra` is enough for that.

Comment: @ar2015: I don't understand your comment about `texlive-latex-extra`

Comment: I mean this is the only answer which works with the current packages of latex installed on my computer. I use Linux and `texlive-latex-extra` includes many commonly used latex packages in Linux.

Comment: @ar2015: Ah, I see. Well, I use the direct TL distribution (complete) without specific Linux package for this (although I use Linux exclusively for production)

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function read_param(filename,paramname)
    for line in io.lines(filename) do
        param,value=string.match(line,"(.*)=(.*)")
        if param==paramname then 
            tex.print(value)
        end
    end
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand{\paraminput}[2][]{\directlua{read_param("#2","#1")}}

The trajectory travels the distance of \paraminput[distance]{parmeters.tex} in 
\paraminput[time]{parmeters.tex}. The simulation stops when the relative error is
less than \paraminput[tolerance]{parmeters.tex}. The maximum observed velocity 
is \paraminput[max_velocity]{parmeters.tex}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided your `parameters.tex` looks like this (with "")

```
time="5 sec"
max_velocity="3 m/s"
tolerance="$10^{-6}$"
start_time="349872034 sec"
stop_time="349872039 sec"
distance="11 m"
```

you could create a noweb file (`so.Rnw`) like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
source( "parameters.tex" )
@

This is an easy - can be done in \Sexpr{time} or less.\\
There is a tolerance of \Sexpr{tolerance} over a distance of \Sexpr{distance}. 

\end{document}
```

and compile it with

```
R CMD Sweave so.Rnw && pdflatex so.tex
```

which gives you

[image]

This may look more complicated but it gives you easy access to real variables and actually is set up  rather easily.

Comment: I took it for granted that you are using `R` - should have mentioned that...