# Add created parameters in child file to main.tex

Tags: datatool, database, write

My code/idea from 2 topics:
[Input a parameter from another file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310977/input-a-parameter-from-another-file)
[filecontents: select rows of group to display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476354/filecontents-select-rows-of-group-to-display/476380#476380)

File `parameters.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{products.tex}
No|Time|Velocity
11|"5s"|"3m/s"
22|"10s"|"7m/s"
33|"20s"|"14m/s"
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{products}{products.tex}
\newcommand{\printtype}[1]{%
  \par
   \DTLforeach*
    [\DTLiseq{\No}{#1}]% Condition
    {products}% Database
    {\No=No,\Time=Time,\Velocity=Velocity}{%
    time = \Time     \par max\_velocity =  \Velocity
    }% 
}

\begin{document}
\printtype{11}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this `parameters.tex` file produces a DVI or PDF file containing:

```
time = 5s
max_velocity = 3m/s
```

But I would like to parse this output from the following `main.tex` file and be able to use the “time” and “max_velocity” values from within `main.tex`.

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \ar_param_file

\seq_new:N \g_ar_param_seq


\cs_new:Nn \ar_read_by_line:n {%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {#1}% Appending the current line to the global sequence buffer
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\paraminput}{O{}m}{%
  \seq_gclear:N \g_ar_param_seq% Clearing the sequence
  \ior_open:Nn \ar_param_file {#2} % Open the input file
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \ar_param_file {\ar_read_by_line:n{##1}}% Reading line by line
  \ior_close:N \ar_param_file% Closing the line
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {% Traversing through the line
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {=} {##1} % Splitting each line into 'key=value' pairs
    \seq_if_in:NxT \l_tmpa_seq {#1} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}\seq_map_break:}% Checking if `#1` is in the sequence and display it with \seq_item:Nn..., then break the mapping loop.
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The trajectory travels the distance of 
\paraminput[time]{parameters.tex}. % <==========================
The maximum observed velocity is \paraminput[max_velocity]{parameters.tex}. ...
\end{document}
```

I use LaTeX, texmarker?
How can I use the parameters output by `parameters.tex` from within `main.tex`? Do I need R or only LaTeX?

Comment: Your `main.tex` reads data in text format, but the lines containing “time = 5s” and “max velocity = 3m/s” produced par your `parameters.tex` (or paramters.tex...) are not written to a text file, they are written do DVI or PDF, depending on  how you compile `parameters.tex`. You could either modify `parameters.tex` to produce a *text file* (using `\write` or a LaTeX3 equivalent), or change your main.tex to read directly from the input file, `products.tex`. I don't know the parsing rules of datatool.sty (double quotes seem to be specially handled), but the second sol. seems more straightforward.

Comment: I've added an answer that minimally modifies your   `parameters.tex` to produce the sentence at the end of your second file. Is this what you want to achieve? If not, please describe it more accurately.

Comment: @frougon can you guide me more about: "modify parameters.tex to produce a text file (using \write or a LaTeX3 equivalent)" - i want to use 2 saparated file: parameter and main.tex. thanks

Comment: Okay, I have replaced my answer. Is this what you want? Note that I used `parameters.txt` for the output file name; `parameters.tex` is not a great name, because the file doesn't use TeX syntax. I also improved the LaTeX3 code and formatting in your `main.tex`, see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484540/73317) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you really want to write to an intermediate file in text format. Here is one way to do that, with `\write` (note that the output file is named `parameters.txt`).

Contents of `parameters.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{products.tex}
No|Time|Velocity
11|"5s"|"3m/s"
22|"10s"|"7m/s"
33|"20s"|"14m/s"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb[autokeys=false]{products}{products.tex}

\newwrite\myOutput
\immediate\openout\myOutput=parameters.txt
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\myOutput}

\newcommand{\printForNumber}[1]{%
  \DTLforeach*%
    [\DTLiseq{\No}{#1}]% Condition
    {products}% Database
    {\No=No,\Time=Time,\Velocity=Velocity}{%
      \immediate\write\myOutput{time=\Time}%
      \immediate\write\myOutput{max_velocity=\Velocity}%
    }%
  }

\begin{document}
\printForNumber{11}
\end{document}
```

This produces a file called `parameters.txt`, containing the following lines:

```
time=5s
max_velocity=3m/s
```

Your `main.tex` code works with that, at the condition that you replace `parameters.tex` with `parameters.txt` in the two `\paraminput[〈param name〉]{〈file〉}` calls. However, the way used in your `main.tex` code to select the first line containing the desired parameter name (here: `time` or `max_velocity`) can be improved a little bit—you'll find my proposal below. The main problem in my opinion is that your equality test for the given parameter name applies to *both* sides of the equal sign: the parameter name (okay) and also the parameter value (not fantastic...).

I also tried to arrange the code according to LaTeX3-recommended code style (see [The LaTeX3 Pro­gram­ming Lan­guage](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) and [LaTeX3 style guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) on [this page](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel)). I moved the whole logic of the `\paraminput` command into a new `\ar_find_data_in_file:nn` protected command, so that the document-level command (`\paraminput`) just calls `\ar_find_data_in_file:nn` with its two arguments. The empty default value for the optional argument of `\paraminput` is strange, but I suppose you are going to replace it with `time`, `max_velocity` or something like that. Therefore, I didn't change this optional argument into a mandatory one. So, here is the revised `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \g_ar_param_file
\seq_new:N \g_ar_param_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ar_read_by_line:n
  {
    % Append the current line to the global sequence \g_ar_param_seq
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ar_param_seq {#1}
  }

% #1: parameter name such as 'time' or 'max_velocity'
% #2: input file
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ar_find_data_in_file:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_ar_param_seq      % Clear the sequence
    \ior_open:Nn \g_ar_param_file {#2} % Open the input file #2
    % Read it line by line into sequence \g_ar_param_seq
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_ar_param_file { \__ar_read_by_line:n {##1} }
    \ior_close:N \g_ar_param_file      % Close the file

    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ar_param_seq % For each line
      { % Split it around the '=' sign
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {=} {##1}
        % Get the parameter name
        \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl

        % If #1 is the name of the parameter for the current line, leave it in
        % the TeX input stream and break out of the mapping loop.
        \str_if_eq:VnT \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
          {
            \seq_map_break:n % Get the parameter value and break
              { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \paraminput { O{} m }
  {
    \ar_find_data_in_file:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The trajectory took \paraminput[time]{parameters.txt}.
The maximum observed velocity was \paraminput[max_velocity]{parameters.txt}.
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of main.pdf]

Comment: thank for your help. But i want 2 file: parameter.tex và main.tex. Not merge. Thanks

Comment: Done, please see above.

Comment: @fourgon: thank. You're my hero. I tested: when i change No = 22 but The result/file parameter.txt not change, always: time = 5s, max_velocity= 3m/s. This parameter.txt is closed. I use Texmaker 5.0.3. One other question: If any, i change no in parameter.tex but compile only one time with main.tex. Don't need compile parameters.tex then compile main.tex. Thanks

Comment: It works here: if I change the first file (`parameters.tex`) to have `\printForNumber{22}` instead of `\printForNumber{11}`, recompile this `parameters.tex` then `main.tex`, I see “The trajectory took 10s. The maximum observed velocity was 7m/s.” in `main.pdf`. You *have* to recompile `parameters.tex` before `main.tex` if you want to see any change, because this is what generates `parameters.txt`, which is the input of `main.tex`. This is the disadvantage when using an intermediate file. That is why my [first solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/484540/3) didn't use one.

Comment: thank for answer. i will try again. Your first Solution is good if main.tex is simple and there are 2-5 parameters. My real main.tex : > 2000 rows, and Parameter > 100 variables.

Comment: Thanks, I sense another problem here: your `parameter.txt` does not contain the `No` field (11, 22, 33) and the algorithm from your `main.tex`, which I kept for the most part, exits as soon as it found a match (`time` or `max_velocity` parameter name). If you have several `\printForNumber{...}` in `parameters.tex`, the way things currently are, only the first one will be used by `main.tex`, because it doesn't do anything to find the data for a *particular row:* it just takes the first one.

Comment: In other words, if you want to write *several rows of data* to `parameters.txt`, it seems to me that you should change its format too, and I am not sure of the benefit as compared to my [first solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/484540/3)...

Comment: thank so much. your both solution are awesome. i will test more each solution then i will select 1 or 2 solution. Thanks