# Can I use a function inside LaTeX to alter portions of \input{}?

Tags: input

I have a table in a LaTeX file, named `tabular.tex` which contains a tabular environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{rr}
Number & Name \\
1      & John \\
2      & Mary \\
\end{tabular}
```

and I input it in my main document with

```
\input{tabular.tex}
```

Can I somehow alter the Number, of say John, to make it 11 instead of 1 from within LaTeX?
I could use `sed` or some other stream editor to make this change externally, but I would like to know if I could do this from within LaTeX.

The reason I ask this is that the actual tabular is huge and I would like to [partially input lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file), so in the end the lines would have consecutive numbering in my LaTeX main document.

Comment: Does `tabular.tex` have to have the numbers 1, 2, ... or could the column be some macro in each line `\printnextnum` which can reference a counter defined in the main document?

Comment: No. And "wow", I think I know where you are going with it. What I think you suggest is create the tabular in such a way so as the first field in each line is a counter, which is specific for this tabular (the document will have many such tabulars, so each one will have each one counter).

Comment: @DaiBowen I will try working with such a solution like in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers and will update.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21244/106162 but the first answer of the question you link to might be the more elegant.

Comment: Thank you very much @DaiBowen I worked with the answer of Seamus, using the `magicrownumbers` counter. Just before each tabular environment I reset the counter with `\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}` and everything works fine for me! Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify if only instances of `1 & John` should be modified, or if all instances of "*any number* followed by `& John`" -- e.g., "22 & John" -- should be modified.

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify the question, I've realised it's perhaps unclear whether you seek to make specific replacements or have some common increment over the tabulars in mind.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your elaborate answer. I will also try to implement it, experiment with it and introduce myself to LuaTeX. "John" is not important, only the number is. So your current answer is more than enough. I am also in a kind of difficult position because I will most probably implement DaiBowen 's answer, because it is more specific and compact for my current needs. However, your answer seems what I had in mind when I was writing the question and it does answer to the title of the question and it's the most versatile as far as I can tell. Thanks once again.

Comment: @pidosaurus - I'll provide an addendum to show how to change `1` to `11` if (and only if) it occurs in the first column of a tabular-like environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the numbers in the first column are hard-coded (`1`, `2`, etc) and if you're free to use LuaLaTeX, it's straightforward to set up a Lua function that scans the input for `1 & John` and, if found, replaces it with `11 & John`. (I assume that instances of `11 & John` and `21 & John` should *not* be modified. Please advise if this assumption is invalid.) It's also straightforward to limit the operation of this function to `tabular`/`tabular*`/`tabular[xy]` environments.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{tabular.tex}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
Number & Name \\
\hline
1      & John \\
21     & John \\
2      & Mary \\
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
-- spring into action only inside a tabular environment
in_tabular = false 
function change_john ( s )
  if string.find ( s , "\\begin{tabular" ) then
    in_tabular = true
  elseif string.find ( s , "\\end{tabular" ) then
    in_tabular = false
  elseif in_tabular then
     -- '%s-' denotes '0 or more instances of whitespace'
     -- In the following code, we allow for up to three such
     -- occurrences (before and after "1", and between "&" and "John")
     return ( string.gsub ( s , "^%s-1%s-&%s-John" , "11 & John" ) )
  end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
   change_john , "change_john" )
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\input tabular \par
If not inside a \texttt{tabular} environment, ``\verb+1 & John+'' does \emph{not} get modified.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's comment that "John" isn't relevant, only "1" is. If you need to change all instances of `1` (but not `11`, `12`, `a.1` or `1.1`) in the first column of a `tabular`-like environment, all you need to change in the Lua code is replace

```
     return ( string.gsub ( s , "^%s-1%s-&%s-John" , "11 & John" ) )
```

with

```
     return ( string.gsub ( s , "^%s-1%s-&" , "11 &" ) )
```

i.e., omit `%s-John` from the search string and `John` from the replacement string.

A (very brief!) Lua string function tutorial: `^` denotes the beginning of a line and `%s-` denotes "zero or more instances of whitespaces". As the Lua function `change_john` is assigned to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates at a very early stage, the `string.gsub` function replaces all matches of `^%s-1%s-&` globally with `"11 &"`, before TeX itself gets to do its usual work.

Answer (score 5):

`\patchcmd` can help:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-table.tex}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
Number & Name \\
1      & John \\
2      & Mary \\
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile,etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef{\mytabular}{\jobname-table.tex}{}
\patchcmd{\mytabular}{1 & John}{11 & John}{}{}
\mytabular

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just for making the example self-contained.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If our `tabular.tex` file is to be used solely for the purpose of this latex, we could consider ourselves free to replace the numbering with a macro to extract the value of the current row counter (See Mico's answer for one way of dealing with such a case).

Since anything `\input` to a tex file is put in context of the rest of the file, the answers to [Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers) can also be used to answer this question.

In this scenario we use a `tabular.tex` of the form:

```
\begin{tabular}{rr}
Number & Name \\
\tablerownum & John \\
\tablerownum & Mary \\
\end{tabular}
```

While in the main document we must define the counter

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tablerowcounter}
\newcommand{\tablerownum}{\stepcounter{tablerowcounter}\arabic{tablerowcounter}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tablerowcounter}{10}
\input{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In order to deal with multiple tabulars (assuming no nesting or similar is going on) a second `\input{tabulartwo}` can be preceded to `\setcounter{tablerowcounter}{1}` to reset the counter as desired.