# Conflict between catchfilebetweentags and a kind of arrow from xypic: argument of \next@ has an extra }

Tags: input, xy-pic, catchfile

I'm using the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4952/1403 to input a part of `file.tex` into another file.

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

at the line `\ExecuteMetaData[file.tex]{tag}`.

Here's a MWE. The file to be recalled is:

```
%<*tag>

\begin{equation}  \xymatrix{A\ar@(ul,ur)^\Sigma }\end{equation}

%</tag>
```

Here is the main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsbook} 
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}

\ExecuteMetaData[file.tex]{tag}

\end{document}
```

The `xypic` code being recalled does work if I don't recall it, but rather write the line directly on the main file.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  That 'solution' is not a self-contained example, so it doesn't really help anyone understand what you are doing (wrong or differently or ...).

Comment: @jon: That's very hard to do in this case, because the error message doesn't tell me at which line of file.tex it is conflicting (line 24 is the ExecuteMetaData line). I tried to make a minimal example that recalls only a line using xypic, but that works. And so I don't really know where the problem is (and the file being inputted is not small, so as to make it easy to deal with). What can I do?

Comment: The normal approach is to 'halve' the document (between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) step by step. If the problem occurs in one half and not the other, then halve that half, and so on. It may be tricky in this case, but I think the principle is likely still sound.  Once the document body problem is sorted out, then progressively strip out packages that seem, a priori, are unrelated to the problem (e.g., if the problem is not about tables, then table-related packages can probably go). Ideally, the minimal document is a small amount of document body and only a few packages.

Comment: @jon: thanks to your advice I was able to provide a really small MWE (or should I say, MNWE...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`catchfilebetweentags` reads the file with the catcode of the @ set to letter. This breaks the `\ar@` command of xypic as it espect the catcode of @ to be "other".

The problem can be demonstrated without external file (see below). I don't see a good way to avoid the `\makeatletter` in `catchfilebetweentags`, it is quite hardcoded and removing it breaks other code. What you can do is to define a command that you use instead of the `\ar@` in the xypic:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{xypic}

\newcommand\myarat{\ar@}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter %done by catchfilebetweentags 
%<*tag>

%\begin{equation}  \xymatrix{A\ar@(ul,ur)^\Sigma }\end{equation} %error

\begin{equation}   \xymatrix{A\myarat(ul,ur)^\Sigma }\end{equation}

%</tag>

\end{document}
```

If you want to keep the `\ar@` you can try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{xypic}


\begin{document}
\CatchFileBetweenTags{\mytemp}{file}{tag}
\scantokens\expandafter{\mytemp}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I would very much like to keep my `\ar@` intact...

Comment: I added a suggestion, could work, but not really tested much.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: What is `mytemp` is the second part of your answer? How would it work with the command `\ExecuteMetaData[file.tex]{tag}`? Thanks