# Command for getting number of lines in another file

Tags: input, include, subfiles, lineno

My goal is to combine several documents into one, so maybe someone can recommend a different solution. More specifically, I need to input about 20 files in a master file, all from line 4 to the second-to-last line, inclusive (I am excluding the `\documentclass` tag, an `\input{header}` tag, and `\begin` and `\end{document}` tags).

I would like to have a command, very similar to @mpg's [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file), except where the second number is relative to the number of lines in the file. For instance, something like

```
\partialinput{4}{-1}{pitest}
```

would be great. Or maybe

```
\partialinput{4}{\linenumber{pitest}-1}{pitest}
```

or similar (where `\linenumber` could be some command that gets the number of lines in the argument file). I would prefer not to use `subfiles', as that would require changing all the headers of the individual files. So, my questions are,

1. Is there a command that gives back the number of lines in another file, or
2. Can the `\partialinput` command be modified to include all but the last line in a document?

I'm not very proficient at TeX or e-TeX, so the structure of the `\partialinput` command is not clear to me. I initially thought that making the counter look one line ahead and stop when it reaches the end would do it, but again, I don't know enough TeX to make that happen.

Comment: I'd be tempted to generate versions of the files to `partialinput` using a suitable set of standard utilities such as `head ` and `tail` called by `write18`. Or `sed`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4908/28808 (this answer would be quite easy to modify)

Comment: why do it this way? It is far simpler just to place the bodies of the documents in separate files and then simply `\input` them.

Comment: Package `catchfilebetweentags` might help

Comment: @ChrisH the document may be typeset on different machines, and I'm not sure `write18` will have the same result.


@DavidCarlisle because I would like each of the smaller documents to be typeset separately - I suppose this is just an organizational and navigational preference.

@ChristianHupfer this is what I ended up using, although I was put off by it because somewhere (can't find the question anymore) @egreg implied that `catchfilebetweentags` never works as expected. But it seems to work for me.