# Import a table and figure from another tex file

Tags: tables, include, xr

Is it possible to include the whole content of the table and figure in another tex file?

Let's say we have A.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

write something here.

\begin{table}[tbp]
    \caption{a}
    {
        \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rrr}
            \toprule
            {test} & {test} & {test} & {test} \\
            \midrule
            {test} & {test} & {test} & {test} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    }
    \label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[tbp]\centering
    \includegraphics[]{test_fig.pdf} 
    \caption{}\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And I want to include the `tab:test` and `fig:test` in B.tex with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[A-][docA.pdf]
\begin{document}
  Tab.~\ref{A-tab:test})
  Fig.~\ref{A-fig:test})
\end{document}
```

This only get the index of the table and figure like `Tab. 2` and `Fig. 10`. Is it able to import both the contents and the indexes of the table and fig in B.tex?
That is, the indexes should still be the same as those A.tex.

Comment: `xr` "[...] implements a system for eXternal References" nothing more nothing less. If you want to have the code in your document, you have to copy it in or do some [gymnastics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/including-parts-of-a-latex-document-in-another-document-without-splitting-up-ori)

Comment: One way to do this is by saving your table and figure in separate .tex files and using \input{yourtable} or \input{yourfigure} in your main .tex file. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @DG' Got it. I'll have a look at the link. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @scd \input{the figure tex file} results in different indexes for the figure. However, I am writing B.tex (a report) based on A.tex by referring. So, the indexes have to be the same.